# Pass an ActiveRecord array through the params hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I pass `@dispensers` through the params hash I get:

```
@dispensers = "[#<Dispenser id: 38084, firstname: \"x\", lastname: \"A Lane\", created_at: \"2014-06-24 20:33:30\", updated_at: \"2014-06-24 20:33:30\", user_id: nil, public: true, birth_date: nil, university_id: nil, business_id: 29, branch_id: 38057, latitude: 30.3509, longitude: -97.7505, score: nil, gmaps: nil, full_name: \"Laura A Lane\", sex: \"F\", premium: false, slug: nil, public_reviews_on: true, bio: nil>, #<Dispenser id: 38102, firstname: \"x\", lastname: \"Woodall\", created_at: \"2014-06-24 20:33:31\", updated_at: \"2014-06-24 20:33:31\", user_id: nil, public: true, birth_date: nil, university_id: nil, business_id: 29, branch_id: 38075, latitude: 30.3379, longitude: -97.7593, score: nil, gmaps: nil, full_name: \"Ashley Woodall\", sex: \"F\", premium: false, slug: nil, public_reviews_on: true, bio: nil>
```

I would like to convert this back to a workable activerecord array, but when I run

`@dispensers.to_a` I see `undefined method 'to_a' for #<String:0x0000000ebf30c0>`

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Jorge, I have worked out a solution.

```
dispensers = params[:dispensers]
array = dispensers.split(',').select{|s| s =~ /Dispenser id/}
ids = array.map {|x| x[/\d+/]}
@dispensers = Dispenser.find(ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an object. You have an string. You can turn the string into an array, and the content of the array wont become an object. If you want to turn this in an object you will have to parse the string. Extract the keys and pass them as parameters to a new instance of the Dispenser class.
This question is mostly related to how to parse this.

This structure seems to be very complicated for something like a single method, perhaps you want to learn about how to build your own parser:

http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/a-quick-intro-to-writing-a-parser-using-treetop.html

Some steps might be:

choping the array symbols, and spliting the objects:

```
array = string[1..-1].split('>,')
```

Then you will have an array of strings of object attributes which you need to turn in a hash with the key as the attribute and the value parsed. And the last step should be creating a new object. (This part is the hardest)

Other option might be extracting the IDS:

```
array = string.split(',').select{|s| s =~ /Dispenser id/}
```

and then

```
ids = array.map {|id| id[17,10].to_i}
```

**Disclaimer:
This is not the best way. And this is not reusable. But for this
question, it might help.**

Comment: Thanks good answer. Do you know how to extract the ids @dispensers?

Comment: By the way, try this for a reusable option array.map {|x| x[/\d+/]}